# about vocab() and Text() in nltk

Tags: python

what does the following codes do? Namely, just the last two lines.
I don't understand what Text() do and what vocab() do?

```
import nltk
 def words(content):
     tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(content) #Make the string into a list of words
     tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]  # remove the stop words
     tokens = [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in tokens] #Lemmatization
     NLTKText = Text(tokens)## remove if nltk is restricted develop new method
     return NLTKText.vocab()
```

What I get after running if is some data structure FreqDist.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.Text) of `nltk` package, `Text()` is

> A wrapper around a sequence of simple (string) tokens, which is intended to support initial exploration of texts (via the interactive console). Its methods perform a variety of analyses on the text’s contexts (e.g., counting, concordancing, collocation discovery), and display the results.

So it is just a wrapper around the given list of strings to provide a simple interface to analyze the corpus given. In particular, [`vocab()`](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html#Text.vocab) returns the frequency distribution of the tokens (words) in the passed list. More about `FreqDist` [here](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html?highlight=freqdist#nltk.probability.FreqDist).

Hope this answers your question.